@Observable class with a class array inside keeps hogging memory
I have an @Observable class in my SwiftUI project that has an array of other classes inside it. I create a slider in the main ContentView that is binded to a variable inside the observable class. This ContentView also has a view that holds data from the array inside the observable class.
The problem happens when I keep sliding the slider, memory allocation keeps on stacking up for as long as I slide the slider. Is there anyway to prevent this?
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ObservableTest
//

import SwiftUI


class thing {
    var variable: UInt8 = 0
    
    init(variable: UInt8 = 0) {
        self.variable = variable
    }
}

@Observable
class ObserveThis {
    var variable: Float = 1
    var things = [[thing]](repeating: [thing](repeating: thing(), count: 512), count: 8)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var observing = ObserveThis()
    
    private let flexibleColumn = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(
                value: $observing.variable,
                in: 0...100,
                step: 5
            ) {
                Text("Variable")
            }
            Text("\(observing.variable)")
            
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: flexibleColumn, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(1...64, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(String(observing.things[0][index].variable))
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            .background(.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
                
            } .padding()
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The memory allocation stays low if I remove the array from the observable class. This was tested on-device with iPhone 13 mini.

Could not replicate your issue (not on a iPhone 13 mini). You could try using struct thing
or @Observable class thing, in both cases it is best to make them Identifiable.
Note, your title is wrong there is no struct in your code.

Make observing Optional and init on onAppear

Thanks for the suggestions. I tried struct thing and making class thing observable with both being Identifiable, but neither helped. Only change that has made a difference so far is adding @ObservationIgnored to var things inside ObserveThis. But this is not a valid solution if I want my view to reflect changes in the array.

I also have confirmed that same happens with an array of Ints instead of array of structs; var numbers = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 100).

@State is just for structs

@State is also meant to be used with the @Observable macro. See here

For now, I have decided to fall back to using ObservableObject as it does not have the same problems.
